# Kodi & RetroPie on one box

Tags: kodi, retropie

Currently I have a Pi 2 set next to my TV running (OSMC) Kodi to stream from my "nas pi B+". I currently use my Android devices as WiFi-remotes.

Next to that is my PS3 used to collect dust.

I was wondering if I could set up my Kodi box to also use the PS3 controllers and play some old-skool snes games etc. and maybe even use the PS3 controllers to navigate menus as well.

I'm going out to buy an Asus bt400 soon.

I have been reading a bit (most useful articles below) on approaches but can't really decide on a stable one.

State of my SD card:

```
    osmc@osmc:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0   15G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 14.8G  0 part /
osmc@osmc:~$ df -lh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        362M     0  362M   0% /dev
tmpfs           367M  5.0M  362M   2% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   15G  1.4G   13G  10% /
tmpfs           367M     0  367M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           367M     0  367M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  240M   28M  212M  12% /boot
tmpfs            74M     0   74M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Will probably plug in some usb dongle to host roms anyway.

> https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup
>
> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=115562
>
> http://blog.petrockblock.com/forums/topic/retropie-multi-boot-images/
>
> http://embedded-software-architecture.com/?page_id=147

**So in short:**
 what is the best approach for running emulators on the same device that would be used as a kodi streamer. Dualboot or otherwise.

And as a bonus: can the ps3 controller double as a Kodi bluetooth remote.

**EDIT:**

I have had no luck so far with the Dual/triple boot NOOBS-installers out there, from "smithers".

Can sombody point me to some github or how-to guide on building similar things?

i.e.

- create dual/tripple boot images
- modify the GUI of OSMC and the other OS's to boot into the other system so I can use a PS3 controller in RetroPie and a WiFi Android controller for OSMC, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the dual/triple boot option using noobs isn't working properly for me (SD-Card issue???)

I wiped my OSMC kodi install from my SD card and installed Retropie 3.3.
From there I use the kodi "app" to get to Kodi. Once there, the wifi android remotes work as they did before.

I have managed to set up the ps3 controller(s) to pair over blue-tooth successfully. This process is actually pretty straight-forward in RetroPie.

This saves me the hassle of switching OS's every time.

Now all I need to do is check is if my ps3 controllers can be configured to control Kodi.

**UPDATE**
In the meantime I do it the other way around. I install OSMC and on top of that I have installed the [retrosmc](https://github.com/mcobit/retrosmc) project. This starts emulationstation from Kodi. Works well for me so far, if not a bit more stable.

Comment: how did you get kodi to run on retropie?

Comment: In the retopie-setup script there is a way to install "experimental" packages, just install the binary install of kodi from there and it will show up under the "ports" menu.

Comment: thank you very much - I was playing around the idea of berrybooting both OSs but this is way better!